# NodeJS/MongoDB - Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I got this helper function:

```
const Account = require('../models/account');

exports.sendInvites = (accountIds, invite, callback) => {

  if (!accountIds) {

    callback('No account ids provided', null, null);

    return;
  }

  accountIds.forEach((id) => {
    Account.findOneAndUpdate({_id: id}, {$push: {organisationInvites: invite}}, callback);
  });
};
```

Then I have this route:

```
router.post('/organisations', auth.verifyToken, (req, res, next) => {

  const organisation = new Organisation({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    admins: [req.body.createdBy],
    createdBy: req.body.createdBy
  });

  organisation.save((err, organisation) => {

    if (err) {

      return res.status(500).json({
        error: err,
        data: null
      });
    }

    organisationUtils.sendInvites(req.body.invites, {
      inviter: req.body.createdBy,
      organisation: organisation._id
    }, (err, account, response) => {

      if (err) {

        return res.status(500).json({
          error: err,
          data: null
        });
      }

      res.json({
        error: null,
        data: organisation
      });
    });
  });
});
```

I get a `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.` error for the

```
res.json({
  error: null,
  data: organisation
});
```

part but I can't understand why this is happening. I tried looking at the accepted answer here [Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client), did some digging but couldn't find any specific reason still what's happening in my particular example above. Any ideas?

Comment: You could not use callback in a loop.Callback must be called after all the db operations has been completed.

Comment: Use async library if you really wants to use callback multiple times. ```https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the callback multiple times, and so `res.json` multiple times. Gather the data from all database request then perform an unique `res.json`.

```
accountIds.forEach((id) => {
    Account.findOneAndUpdate(
                              {_id: id}, 
                              {$push: {organisationInvites: invite}},
                               callback,
                            );
});
```

---

Something like :

```
    var allData = [];
    var nbRequestDone = 0;

    var waitAllCallback = function (data, err) {
       if (err) {
         callback(err);

         nbRequestDone = accountIds.length;

         return;
       }

       nbRequestDone += 1;

       allData.push(data);

       if (nbRequestDone === accountIds.length) {
         callback(false, allData);
       }
    };

    accountIds.forEach((id) => {
      Account.findOneAndUpdate(..., waitAllCallback);
    });
```

Comment: So I tried it and it works, however sometimes the request doesn't return a response to the client side. Any idea why that could be?

Comment: Did you checked if the error got returned? (first parameter)

Comment: I think I resolved it. There was a condition check which failed half of the times, reason unknown. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this video covers the Error regarding "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent". 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rKTlakY8j2M

In summary of the video, this error shows up when you have an extra callback in your code. Hope this helps. Been struggling with this one too for quite some time.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the [essential parts of the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.